# Apache Hudi schema evolution

Tags: schema, apache-hudi

Can anyone share the right approach for handling schema changes in apache hudi? Example: renaming a column from col1 to col2 or changing the data type from long to int.
(Pyspark)

Answer (score 0):

hudi supports avro schema compatibility, so do not support renaming and changing from long to int (int to long is supported). And there are some discussions about supporting full schema evolution in community.